# Windows 7 + bluetooth headphones sound plays just from 1 application

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, bluetooth

I have bluetooth speakers (Bluedio Revolution). Everything works fine if I use just 1 application but if I start another one then the sound can play only 1 source of sound. For example: I am listening music online via Firefox browser. Then I am starting Chrome browser and launch youtube. Then the music from Firefox stops playing and the sound "switches" to the youtube. Is it possible to play sound from both application at the same time?